# Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, cpanel, odbc

Estoy intentando conectar a una base de datos SQL Server, ya configure las extensiones pdo al igual que la de obdc de php en el Cpanel de mi hosting pero me sigue mostrando este error

**Falló la conexión: SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712**

No se como instalar ese driver en mi cpanel, le agradezco si pueden ayudar

Comment: Recuerda que el código, así como mensajes de error deben estar en formato de texto y no en imagen. Por otro lado, una cosa son las extensiones ODBC y otra muy distinta el driver ODBC. El error claramente indica que te falta el driver, y te provee un link para que puedas buscar más información. Mira esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34401170/this-extension-requires-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-11-for-sql-server-to-communica) del sitio en inglés, aunque está algo desactualizada. Saludos

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, pero mi inconveniente es que no se como instalarlo desde el cpanel, ya que todo ese proceso lo hice en local y todo funciona ok, pero en mi hosting no se como instalar ese driver desde CPANEL

Comment: Tal vez debas comunicarte con el soporte técnico de tu hosting y plantearles el problema. No creo que aquí te podamos ayudar con eso. Saludos